# labelling in pheatmap at a particular column

Tags: r, label, pheatmap

I have a dataframe with 152 rows and 300 columns. 
Showing you first 3 rows and all 300 columns

```
genea   2500    2691    genea   191.0   +   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.531231   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.340855   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.190376   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.451626    0.903252    0.903252    0.654369    0.654369    0.778811    0.903252    0.903252    -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.340855   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.809625    1.619250    1.619250    1.257220    1.257220    1.057214    0.857208    0.857208    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.190376   -0.380752   -0.380752   0.672255    0.672255    0.672255    0.672255    0.672255    0.903252    0.903252    1.422216    1.941180    1.941180    1.508340    1.508340    1.912020    2.315700    2.315700    3.317330    3.317330    3.840005    4.362680    4.362680    3.508340    3.508340    3.128800    2.749260    2.749260    3.531090    3.531090    2.982865    2.434640    2.434640    1.975690    1.975690    2.516920    3.058150    3.058150    5.556610    5.556610    5.922590    6.288570    6.288570    2.056200    2.056200    2.563420    3.070640    3.070640    3.577700    3.577700    4.076065    4.574430    4.574430    4.008980    4.008980    4.648165    5.287350    5.287350    5.550990    5.550990    3.810200    2.069410    2.069410    0.000000    0.000000    1.584965    3.169930    3.169930    3.169930    3.169930    3.243285    3.316640    3.316640    4.766030    4.766030    4.925570    5.085110    5.085110    6.746300    6.746300    6.693390    6.640480    6.640480    5.850710    5.850710    5.628100    5.405490    5.405490    4.830740    4.830740    5.017090    5.203440    5.203440    6.095880    6.095880    6.392065    6.688250    6.688250    6.337030    6.337030    5.835895    5.334760    5.334760    4.836420    4.836420    4.736225    4.636030    4.636030    3.659990    3.659990    4.325255    4.990520    4.990520    4.756270    4.756270    2.378135    0.000000    0.000000    3.700440    3.700440    3.921625    4.142810    4.142810    4.318290    4.318290    4.490965    4.663640    4.663640    4.643860    4.643860    3.706855    2.769850    2.769850    2.878250    2.878250    3.156445    3.434640    3.434640    3.676790    3.676790    3.867180    4.057570    4.057570    4.192870    4.192870    4.521820    4.850770    4.850770    4.602990    4.602990    4.119790    3.636590    3.636590    3.899620    3.899620    4.155710    4.411800    4.411800
chr11   62841618    62841809    geneb   191.0   -   -0.613539   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.228451   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.152301   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.038075   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.342677   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.228451   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.152301   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.228451   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.152301   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.068171   -0.681710   -0.681710   0.269267    0.903252    0.857144    0.442170    0.442170    0.718819    0.903252    0.812927    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.068171   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.651614   -0.380752   -0.380752   0.447699    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.350976    1.584960    1.626464    2.000000    2.000000    1.400000    1.000000    0.900000    0.000000    0.000000    1.550976    2.584960    2.584960    2.584960    2.584960    0.805533    -0.380752   -0.180752   1.619250    1.619250    2.198676    2.584960    2.743457    4.169930    4.169930    4.612106    4.906890    4.874697    4.584960    4.584960    3.633984    3.000000    2.858496    1.584960    1.584960    3.348120    4.523560    4.523560    4.523560    4.523560    1.809424    0.000000    0.370044    3.700440    3.700440    3.824310    3.906890    3.862144    3.459430    3.459430    3.427222    3.405750    3.561390    4.962150    4.962150    5.458362    5.789170    5.720218    5.099650    5.099650    4.866226    4.710610    4.661025    4.214760    4.214760    3.676302    3.317330    3.349619    3.640220    3.640220    4.456088    5.000000    5.032193    5.321930    5.321930    5.101292    4.954200    4.852898    3.941180    3.941180    4.168286    4.319690    4.374439    4.867180    4.867180    4.999348    5.087460    4.978714    4.000000    4.000000    2.550976    1.584960    1.688389    2.619250    2.619250    2.619250    2.619250    2.357325    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.332193    3.321930    3.321930    3.321930    3.321930    3.335680    3.459430    3.459430    3.068182    2.807350    2.807350    2.807350    2.807350    2.922940    3.000000    2.800000    1.000000    1.000000    0.400000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.038075   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   0.447699    1.000000
chr17   43367899    43368087    genec   188.0   -   0.000000    1.600000    2.000000    2.000000    2.000000    2.000000    2.000000    2.000000    1.400000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.204513   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.136342   0.000000    -0.114226   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.266526   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.204513   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.477197   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.114226   -0.380752   -0.380752   0.419248    0.619248    0.619248    0.619248    0.619248    0.923850    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    0.200000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1.267968    1.584960    1.584960    1.584960    1.584960    0.316992    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.800000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    0.200000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.300000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    0.700000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.800000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    0.200000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1.267968    1.584960    1.584960    1.584960    1.584960    0.316992    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.300000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    0.700000    0.000000    0.000000    1.600000    2.000000    2.974379    5.247930    5.247930    5.674674    5.781360    5.694507    5.491850    5.491850    3.623866    3.156870    3.505008    4.317330    4.317330    5.117330    5.317330    5.650009    6.426260    6.426260    6.155220    6.087460    6.087460    6.087460    6.087460    5.180852    4.954200    4.464519    3.321930    3.321930    3.934354    4.087460    3.936710    3.584960    3.584960    3.252936    3.169930    2.994439    2.584960    2.584960    4.030848    4.392320    4.371203    4.321930    4.321930    4.532354    4.584960    4.722789    5.044390    5.044390    5.044390    5.044390    4.413427    2.941180    2.941180    2.141180    1.941180    2.320089    3.204210    3.204210    3.040842    3.000000    3.000000    3.000000    3.000000    0.600000    0.000000    0.996579    3.321930    3.321930    3.431930    3.459430    3.459430    3.459430    3.459430    0.387284    -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.380752   -0.076150   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    -0.204513   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.681710   -0.477197   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

I am plotting the values in this dataframe using pheatmap function as follows:

```
pheatmap(dmat,
         scale="none",
         cluster_rows = FALSE,
         cluster_cols = FALSE,
         annotation_names_col = FALSE,
         show_colnames= FALSE,
         color = colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(n = 7, name ="RdYlBu")))(500),
         main = "figure1",
         border_color = NA
)
```

I want to add a label at 200th column "TSS" on this pheatmap generated above. What code should I use for that? "TSS" should appear in the last row and 200th column
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just did, let me know if this does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution based on grobs.

```
library(pheatmap)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(grid)

# Generate data 
nc <- 300
nr <- 152
ref <- 200  # The column where you need to add a label   
dmat <- matrix(runif(nr*nc), ncol=nc)
dmat[,ref] <- 0

q <- pheatmap(dmat,
         scale="none",
         cluster_rows = FALSE,
         cluster_cols = FALSE,
         annotation_names_col = FALSE,
         show_colnames= FALSE,
         color = colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(n = 7, name ="RdYlBu")))(500),
         main = "Figure1",
         border_color = NA
)

downViewport("matrix.4-3-4-3")
grid.text("TSS", x=ref/nc, y=1, vjust=-0.5, gp=gpar(col="red", fontface=2, fontsize=12))
popViewport()
```

[image]

The list of available viewports generated by `pheatmap` can be retrieved using

```
 grid.draw(q)
 current.vpTree()
 # viewport[ROOT]->(viewport[layout]->(viewport[layout]->
 #    (viewport[main.1-3-1-3], viewport[legend.4-5-5-5], viewport[matrix.4-3-4-3])))
```

Comment: Hi this looks good, Is there a way I don't have blue line in the heatmap, just TSS label?

Comment: @user3138373 The blue line was generated by `dmat[,ref] <- 0` with the only aim to show that the label was correctly placed. Try my code with your data and the blue line will dissapear.

Comment: Hi Thanks again, if I want to get the label "TSS" at the bottom, I tried changing y=1 to y=brow(dmat), but that didn't help. ANy idea how I can get TSS to be displayed at the bottom?

Comment: @user3138373 The lower-left corner has coordinates `x=0` and `y=0`; the lower-right corner has coordinates `x=0` and `y=1`